# GitKraken - How to exit fullscreen mode?

Tags: gitkraken

I've entered fullscreen mode and now it seems impossible to exit it via the GUI.

How can I leave fullscreen mode again once entered?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can toggle Fullscreen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: It is not possible via GUI?

Comment: It is possible via GUI. Open "View" menu and select "Toggle Full Screen"

Comment: I had the same issue in CentOS, and when I am in fullscreen, I don't see menus, so only shortcut is working... Quite frustrating experience !

Comment: why not a more standard F11 toggle?

Comment: Why does it not reset after you restart? I've had it in full screen for over a month now, thinking something broke.. I reinstalled it and everything too..

Comment: rofl @ItsGreg I think it's ridiculous they didn't at least have the standard F11 as an alternative. I dont know what Antwane is talking about, seeing as that entire bar with the View option disappears when you enter fullscreen mode

Comment: @Antwane I haven't found any alternative other than ctl-shift-F. In full screen mode the menu doesn't exist (at least on my version).  I killed GitKraken as well the first time it happened ;-) It would be useful to note any other means of exiting, as some are easier to remember than others.

Comment: This feature was created with StackOverflow in mind.

Answer (score 8):

Ctrl+Shift+F 
or edit ~/.gitkraken/config

Comment: Been living with this for months. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Alt + F will display the menu again.
Then click on the "View" item and then click the "Toggle Full Screen" menu item.

Comment: Alt+F and then navigating the menus with the arrow keys worked for me. The Ctr+Shift+F combination got intercepted by the Ctr+Shit combination that I had already assigned to a keyboard layout change. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can change it in GitKraken settings. Change setting `windowSettings/fullScreen` to `false` in the file `~/.gitkraken/config`

Answer (score 0):

alt + space will display the menu items. From there you click "default" and it goes back into the default screensize

Comment: Not intiutive at all.